# Org-Capture-Template portablility in Windows and Crostini

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I’ve been using `org-mode` for my GTD system for a little while and now that I’m happy with it I decided to set it up on all my computers. My main machine for the last year or so has been on Archlinux and that’s where I did my setup originally now I’ve added a windows computer and a Pixelbook running Emacs in crostini. I’m syncing my org files with Dropbox and that works fine. I’ve copied my `.emacs` file to each computer and changed some file paths for my windows machine. Almost everything seems to be working fine except for something strange with my Capture Templates.

On the Pixelbook the Templates using file+olp+datetree throws an `invalid capture target specification` ie:

```
("m" "Meeting Note" entry

(file+olp+datetree "~/Dropbox/org/Journal.org" "Meetings")

"* Description: %^{Description|Meeting} %T

- Participants: %^{Participants}

- Location: %^{Location}

** Notes:

- %?

** Next Steps: :ReFile:

- [ ] ")
```

On the windows computer my Inbox ToDo capture throws the same error in the minibuffer:

```
("t" "New TODO to Inbox" entry

(file "C:/Users/jgallo/Dropbox/org/GTD.org" "Inbox")

"* TODO %?" :prepend :time-prompt t)
```

Anyone have any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

The `file+olp+datetree` target expects just one argument, the filename. The same is true of the `file` target in your Windows configuration. If you want to use a headline for the target, you can use `file+headline`.

The details of these can be seen in the Org manual at [Org capture template elements](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements)